# Using function inside module in Shiny - working with namespace

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My idea is to create multiple elements that have `radioGroupButtons` and `plotlyOutput` in a `module` file.
To avoid repetitions I created a function like this bellow:

```
tabpanel_content <- function(radio_id, plotly_id){


  div(
    id = "div_1",
    style = "",

    div(
      class = "inputs ",
      style = "width: 100%",

      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = ns(radio_id),
        label = "",
        choices = c("Input_1","Input_2"),
        status = "success"
      )
    ),

    div(style = "",

        plotlyOutput(ns("plotly_id"), height = 200,width = "auto"))
  )
}
```

the changes are on `radioGroupButtons` and `plotlyOutput` ids.

Then I include this function on the module file:

```
mod_1_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(

    tabsetPanel(

      tabPanel(
        strong("TabPanel - Title"),

        tabpanel_content(radio_id = 'radio_input_1',plotly_id = 'plotly_chart_1'),
        tabpanel_content(radio_id = 'radio_input_2',plotly_id = 'plotly_chart_2'),
        tabpanel_content(radio_id = 'radio_input_3',plotly_id = 'plotly_chart_3'),


  )))
}

mod_1_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

    }
  )
}
```

And then I include the `module` on the `app` file:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


source(file = 'module_1.R')
source(file = 'input_functions_1.R')

ui <- fluidPage(

  mod_1_UI("mod_1")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I have this error Message: ***Error in ns(radio_id) : could not find function "ns"***

I think the relation between my `tabpanel_content` function and the `module` function is the problem. To create something like this, is this the best practice?

Any help?

Comment: `NS`, not `ns`. And here you have to remove the quotes: `ns("plotly_id")`.

Comment: I am this message error here: `Error in paste0(inputId, "-label") : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `ns` in the function:

```r
tabpanel_content <- function(radio_id, plotly_id) {
  div(
    id = "div_1",
    style = "",
    div(
      class = "inputs ",
      style = "width: 100%",
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = radio_id,
        label = "",
        choices = c("Input_1", "Input_2"),
        status = "success"
      )
    ),
    div(
      style = "",
      plotlyOutput(plotly_id, height = 200, width = "auto")
    )
  )
}
```

Use it in the module:

```r
mod_1_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        strong("TabPanel - Title"),
        tabpanel_content(
          radio_id = ns("radio_input_1"), plotly_id = ns("plotly_chart_1")
        ),
        tabpanel_content(
          radio_id = ns("radio_input_2"), plotly_id = ns("plotly_chart_2")
        ),
        tabpanel_content(
          radio_id = ns("radio_input_3"), plotly_id = ns("plotly_chart_3")
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```